# linq aggregated nested count

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

i have the following classes:

```
class Outer
{
   public ICollection<Inner> Inners
}

class Inner
{
    public ICollection<Inner> Inners
}
```

I would like to order descending a list of outers by the total count of their Inners and nested Inners.

for example:

if i have 2 outers: the first has a collection of 3 inners, each with 1 nested inner then total is 5.

the second has for example can have a collection of 2 inners, each with 3 nested inner then 
the total count is 2 + 3 + 3 = 8

therefor in the returned result the second example should be the first.

Anyone? :)

Comment: Shouldn't the total in the first example be 6, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, build a recursive method to count the Inner objects inside a `Inner` object including itself:

```
public static int Count(Inner inner)
{
    var count = 1;
    if (inner.Inners != null && inner.Inners.Any())
       count += inner.Inners.Sum(x => Count(x));

    return count;
}
```

Then you can order:

```
var result = outers.OrderBy(o => o.Inners.Sum(i => Count(i)));
```